# Suds and "mismatched tag"

Tags: python, web-services, soap, suds

I'm using Suds to consume a soap webservices (debug mode on).

I call the wsdl with no problem

```
from suds.client import Client
client = Client('https://ipwebservice?wsdl')
```

printing

```
print client
```

I obtain some info about the webservice: only one "service", on a unique port, some methods and some types.

But, when I try to call a method passing a simple parameter

```
result = client.service.method('test')
```

I obtain this error:

```
xml.sax._exceptions.SAXParseException: <unknown>:4:2: mismatched tag
```

If I try to consume/send the same envelope with SoapUI I've no problem.

Comment: One mismatched thing would be the missing closing apostrophe in `Client('https://ipwebservice?wsdl)`.

Comment: sorry, is only an error of copy/paste. Unfortunately isn't the "real" problem :)

Comment: @Vito Is there a module and line number printed with your error?

Comment: here the complete traceback: http://pastie.org/6353141 . Seems that the WS responds not in xml/soap rather in a webpage